# Icon that resembles "< >" in Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

Referring to the Fiddler's User Interface guide: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/uiguide

It seems deprecated, since it still uses the old-style logos despite the redesign.

What does the `< >` icon stand for?

[image]

The closest alternative from the old logos are XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, the website's icons haven't been updated. `< >` refers to HTML.

Here's a screenshot of all of the icons from [the Fiddler book](http://fiddlerbook.com/): 
[image: Fiddler Session list icons]